# Should I use single Tweepy instance for multiple bots or create a new one for each?

Tags: python, api, object, twitter, tweepy

I'm creating several Twitter bots using Tweepy. All of those run on the same account so the api keys and tokens are same.

Let's say one bot likes tweets. Another bot retweets tweets. Should I create a separate Tweepy for each one or should I create one instance and use that in all bots? What is the better practice?

Comment: do you mean Different twitter account or different scripts by Twitter bots?

Comment: different scripts, same twitter account